# Does this F-star solar system make sense?

Tags: internal-consistency, orbital-mechanics, astronomy, solar-system

The setting for the narrative project me and my team are working on is a solar system with centred by an F-star 1.3 to 1.32 times more massive than the sun aged 2.5 to 3 Billion years.

Here is how the planets would be placed:

The protagonists of the system would be 7 giants: 4 gas giants and 3 ice giants.

2 gas giants in the habitable zone (2 AUs and 3 AUs respectively post migration), 2 gas giants (10 AUs to 15 AUs) in the outer system and 3 ice giants in the far edge (20 to 30 AUs)

Each of these giants would have extensive moon systems, akin to those of saturn and jupiter, especially those in the outer system given that they didn't migrate.

Those that migrated on the other hand would have moon systems as well, specifically several galilean moons, consisting of inner planets that were either captured or that were torn apart by their gravity and re-initated moon formation around the giants.

One of these gas giants, the one at 2AUs from the star and possessing a mass 3 times that of jupiter captured a satellite that has a mass 0.7 times that of earth and is the only life-bearing body of the system.

Needless to say the migration of the two giants led to the formation of two asteroid belts, one circling the sun and one in the habitable zone.

Is this solar system realistic? And are there specific guidelines to decide the masses of the other planets?

Comment: I don't have the math to give a real answer but my gut says that the two gas giants in the habitable zone would be too close to each other to be long term stable.  Maybe if they were into some kind of mutual harmonic relationship it would work but that's far beyond my stellar physics understanding.

Comment: ShadoCat Noted, I'll move it away and I'll consider cutting it even, thank you for your input

Comment: You might be able to experiment with your ideas via Super Planet Crash : http://www.stefanom.org/spc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this solar system realistic? And are there specific guidelines to decide the masses of the other planets?

I put these conditions into [Universe Sandbox](https://universesandbox.com) and ran the simulation out a few million years. Yes, this system does work and is stable for that amount of time.

[image]

Comment: James McLellan Oh wow, thanks! Though...how does it look like for longer like a couple billion years or so?

Comment: @JuimyTheHyena at that point the uncertainties in the software would surely create a wrong result.

Comment: BMF Oh...makes sense. Then I'd consider the case closed.